# Azure Scaling an API Options

Tags: azure, api, microservices, azure-batch

Using Azure features, how can we scale compute resources for an api/microservice prior to calling the API
a) we need ability to specify infrastructure and performance features
b) setup the API on that infrastructure
c) then call the API while it is up/running for logging, status-ing
d) shutdown on command that infrastructure

This sounds like it is scenario for Azure Batch.

Would this work? Create a linux image with the API setup, then use Azure Batch to create a pool specifying the image.  There would not really be a task however I just need the image up/running so our application could submit to the image and API that was up and running.

Is this the best approach? (can you have a pool that starts without a real task and keeps up/running so we could execute an API that is exposed on it?)

Keep in mind, on the next API call we would repeat by creating a new pool with different compute requirements for the particular api call.

Comment: Are there timing restrictions? Meaning, how much delay is accepted for the worker service to start up? What will run on the worker node and how long are they expected to run?

Comment: I assume the linux image would stay "UP" running until the calling code that created the pool and image would shut it down.  As it is just surfacing and API/web app the task itself would not know when to shut down.  Still not sure this is the most appropriate approach but thinking is this viable?

It does seem on surface odd to have a pool/task for an API that doesn't have a auto stop.